# Pycharm module installation specific directory

Tags: module, installation, pycharm

Is there a way to install a module into a specific directory in Pycharm using the settings/available packages method (i.e. not PIP)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From pycharm,

The user has to select the `venv` for each project. So if the user requires any python packages,

goto `settings` -> `project Interpreter`

Click on `+` button on top right corner and you will get pop-up window of Available packages. Then search for the python package.

Then click on Install package to install the package.

So it will install the package in the `venv` which the user selected:

`venv` -> `Lib`.